# MySQL Query/Table in need of optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query that is taking an embarrassingly long time. ~7 minutes embarrassing. I would really appreciate some help. Missing indexes? Rewrite the query? All of the above?

Many thanks

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64)

The query looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, name 
FROM api_events ae
INNER JOIN products p on p.token=ae.product_token 
WHERE (ae.created_at > '2019-01-21 12:16:53.853732') 
GROUP BY name
```

Here are the two table definitions

**api_events** has ~31 *million* records

```
CREATE TABLE `api_events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `api_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `hostname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `controller_action` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `duration` decimal(12,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `view` decimal(12,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `db` decimal(12,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `product_token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_token` (`product_token`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64851218 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and
**products** has only 12 records

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Why is token varchar(50), and product_token varchar(255)?

Comment: I would suggest using range partitioning on **created_at** for **api_events** table. For more details take a look -  [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-range.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-range.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could improve the join performance adding index

```
create index  idx1 on api_events(product_token, created_at);

create index  idx2 on products(token);
```

You could also trying inverting  the columns ofr api_events

```
 create index  idx1 on api_events(created_at, product_token);
```

and trying add  redundancy to product index

```
create index  idx2 on products(token, name);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't suggest a foreign key instead of two indexes? Edit: Never mind, I just saw that MySql doesn't seem to add indexes implicitly when adding foreign keys.

Comment: @FlorianLim  the adding of the constraint id a design  choice  ... the adding of index  if performance choose  .. so in this case  i have suggested  the index .. part

Comment: @scaisEdge the new indexes vastly improved the performance

I'm at ~17 seconds now...inestimably better, but still really long

is that as good as I can expect?

Comment: I have update the answer  with some suggestion  ..  .. I don't know how many rows you have in both tables  and the features  of you server  . .. but if the suggestion don't improve further then  the last change are the hardware features and  db storage tuning  (more complex that index sure)

Answer (score 1):

For the query as stated, you needed

```
api_events:  INDEX(created_at, product_token)
products:    INDEX(token, name)
```

Because the `WHERE` mentions api_events, the Optimizer is likely to start with that table.  `created_at` is in the `WHERE`, so the index starts with that, even though starting with a 'range' is usually wrong.  In this case, the pair is "covering".

Then, `INDEX(token, name)` is also "covering".

"Covering" indexes give a small, but widely varying, amount of performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you group by the token instead of the `name`?

```
SELECT ae.product_token, COUNT(*) AS count_all 
FROM api_events ae
WHERE ae.created_at > '2019-01-21 12:16:53.853732')
GROUP BY ae.product_token;
```

For this query, an index on `api_events(created_at, product_token)` will probably help.

If this is faster, then you can bring in the name using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the criteria on `created_at` is very selective (looking at only the past 7 days?).  That's crying out to explore an index with `created_at` as a leading column.

The query is also referencing the `product_token` column from the same table, so we can include that column in the index, to make it a covering index.

```
  api_events_IX ON api_events ( created_at, product_token )
```

Using that index, we can probably avoid looking at the vast majority of the 31 million rows, and quickly narrow in on the subset of rows we actually need to look at.

Using the index, the query will still need a "Using filesort" operation to satisfy the GROUP BY.

(My guess here is that the join to the 12 rows in product doesn't exclude a lot of   rows... that on the vast majority of rows in `api_event` the `product_token` refers to a row that exists in `product`.

---

Use MySQL `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan.

---

A further possible refinement (to test the performance of) would be to do some of the aggregation in an inline view:

```
 SELECT SUM(s.count_all) AS count_all
      , p.name
   FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all
               , ae.product_token
            FROM api_events ae
           WHERE ae.created_at > '2019-01-21 12:16:53.853732'
           GROUP
              BY ae.product_token
        ) s
   JOIN products p 
     ON p.token = s.product_token 
  GROUP
     BY p.name
```

---

If the assumption about `product_token` is misinformed, if there are lots of rows in `api_event` that have `product_token` values that don't reference a row in `product` ... we might take a different tack ...